# Not able to access particular data from a List<Rootobject> object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a json file, which I have deserialized and added the data to `List<Rootobject>`.

The json file is as below.

{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}}
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}}
{"_id":1283378,"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}}

It has 2,00,000 such rows.

I have deserialized it as below.

```
public List<Rootobject> list=new List<Rootobject>();
public List<Rootobject> ReadAllCities()
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Assets/city_list.json");
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(line);
        list.Add(res);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Now I want to just retrieve the "name" property from the list and create a `List<String>` object. I am trying to do that using `foreach`. But I am getting compilation error.

It says Rootobject does not contain a definition for name.

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Rootobject` is defined as...

```
public class Rootobject {
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
}
```

and `list` is...

```
public List<Rootobject> list = new List<Rootobject>();
```

populated with objects.

You can use LINQ to select the `name`

```
List<string> namesList = list.Select(i => i.name).ToList();
```

or if you want to use `foreach`...

```
List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in list) {
    string name = item.name;
    namesList.Add(name);
}
```

Comment: @TusharKantaPrusty, Glad to help. If this resolves your question then you can mark it as answered. Thanks. Happy coding!!!

Comment: I have performance problem now. Since, my json file has 2,00,000 lines, after I type something in my search box, its taking 15-20 seconds to suggest something.

Comment: Ok that question is outside of the scope of this one. Ask a new question and link it. I'll give it a look. I have a few ideas.

Comment: Ok..posted a new question.